# Sort Map of Maps based on one of the nested values

Tags: sorting, groovy

```
def map = [
  P1: [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York"],
  P2: [name:"Long", age: 25, city: "New York"],
  P3: [name:"Dustin", age: 29, city: "New York"],
  P4: [name:"Dustin", age: 34, city: "New York"]];
```

I have the above map, I want to sort the map based on the age

Comment: What have you tried so far?  As a quick note "Map" doesn't necessarily have an order unless you are using a LinkedHashMap (which is the default in Groovy...but just so you know)

Comment: Updated the title, as there are no lists here, it's all maps

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def map = [
  P1: [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York"],
  P2: [name:"Long", age: 25, city: "New York"],
  P3: [name:"Dustin", age: 29, city: "New York"],
  P4: [name:"Dustin", age: 34, city: "New York"]]
  
def sortedByAge = map.sort { entry ->
    entry.value.age
}
```